# Find Error When Using Codec

Tags: mongodb-java

I have a simple object named Tag that has an id, name, and three numeric properties. I also have a codec for the object. The folloing code executes without error.

```
MongoDatabase tagsDatabase = 
    usersProcess.getMongoClient().getDatabase(tagsDB)
    .withCodecRegistry(usersProcess.getCodecRegistry());
MongoCollection<Tag> tagsCollection = 
    tagsDatabase.getCollection(tagsCollectionName, Tag.class);
    ArrayList<Tag> tagsList = new ArrayList<Tag>();
FindIterable<Tag> tagsByAlpha = 
    tagsCollection.find().sort(Sorts.ascending("name"));
```

Following this, the code

```
tagsByAlpha.forEach(new Consumer<Tag>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Tag t) {
                tagsList.add(t);
            }
        });
```

thows the exception "org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readEndArray can only be called when ContextType is ARRAY, not when ContextType is DOCUMENT" at the first line (forEach). An alternative construct

```
 MongoCursor<Tag> tagsCursor = tagsByAlpha.iterator();
```

throws the same exception. It seems to be implying that find() has returned Documents rather than Tag objects. At the same time, the code that does work suggests that what I'm trying is possible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After deleting the collection''s documents, the forEach loops don't execute and no error is shown. I belive that the problem is in my Bson codec, which rashly assumes that that mongo data unerlying a Double is a BigDecimal (what else could it be?).

Answer (score 0):

Should have used org.bson.codecs.DoubleCodec